# JUnit assertions : make the assertion between floats

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I need to compare two values : one a string and the other is float
so I convert the string to float then try to call `assertEquals(val1,val2)` but this is not authorized , I guess that the `assertEquals` doesn't accept float as arguments.

What is the solution for me in this case ?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You have to provide a delta to the assertion for Floats:

```
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, delta)
```

While delta is the maximum difference (delta) between expected and actual for which both numbers are still considered equal.

```
Assert.assertEquals(0.0012f, 0.0014f, 0.0002); // true
Assert.assertEquals(0.0012f, 0.0014f, 0.0001); //false
```

Answer (score 15):

A delta-value of 0.0f also works, so for old fashioned "==" compares (use with care!), you can write

```
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, 0.0f);
```

instead of

```
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual); // Deprecated
Assert.assertTrue(expected == actual); // Not JUnit
```

I like the way JUnit ensures that you really thought about the "delta" which should only be 0.0f in really trivial cases.

Comment: I would suggest using the 0.0f (including an answer edit with bold text) over the others beacause it's more semantic. I didn't know about this issue and the 0.0f could lead me to understand what's intended. With the deprecated or "Not JUnit" way it would be less obvious.