# How to round a double/float to BINARY precision?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, rounding, precision

I am writing tests for code performing calculations on floating point numbers. Quite expectedly, the results are rarely exact and I would like to set a tolerance between the calculated and expected result. I have verified that in practice, with double precision, the results are always correct after rounding of last two significant decimals, but *usually* after rounding the last decimal. I am aware of the format in which `double`s and `float`s are stored, as well as the two main methods of rounding (precise via `BigDecimal` and faster via multiplication, `math.round` and division). As the mantissa is stored in binary however, is there a way to perform rounding using base 2 rather than 10?

Just clearing the last 3 bits almost always yields equal results, but if I could push it and instead 'add 2' to the mantissa if its second least significast bit is set, I could probably reach the limit of accuracy. This would be easy enough, expect I have no idea how to handle overflow (when all bits 52-1 are set).

A Java solution would be preferred, but I could probably port one for another language if I understood it.

EDIT:
As part of the problem was that my code was generic with regards to arithmetic (relying on `scala.Numeric` type class), what I did was an incorporation of rounding suggested in the answer into a new numeric type, which carried the calculated number (floating point in this case) and rounding error, essentially representing a range instead of a point. I then overrode equals so that two numbers are equal if their error ranges overlap (and they share arithmetic, i.e. the number type).

Comment: If you want to compare float variables in test only then your question is duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554281/junit-assertions-make-the-assertion-between-floats

Comment: What's wrong, exactly, with clearing the last three bits?  Is it that you want to round-to-nearest instead of floored?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very reliable way to test for approximate equality, as you could be comparing two adjacent floating point numbers which happen to round different directions (if you do enough tests, this situation will happen eventually).

Comment: 1. I can't easily use the obvious delta/tolerance solution as the code that does comparing is _not_ directly inside the test, but it's an equality check deeper in the stack of the tested  code (and the code operates on arbitrary numeric types, floating points being only one of them)

Comment: So you're saying the check has to be of the form `f(a) == f(b)`? In that case there's not much you can do, as there are always going to be cases where that `a` & `b` are close, but `f(a) != f(b)` (unless `f(a) = const`).

Comment: You are right. I originally presumed that by requesting only a fixed precision, I can make results exactly correct as long as the function is accurate enough, but more careful reasoning proved it to not be the case. I was trying to be lazy-smart, but it looks like the code needs to be made aware about requested accuracy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, rounding off binary digits makes more sense than going through `BigDecimal` and can be implemented very efficiently if you are not worried about being within a small factor of `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

You can round a floating-point `double` value `x` with the following sequence in Java (untested):

```
double t = 9 * x; // beware: this overflows if x is too close to Double.MAX_VALUE
double y = x - t + t;
```

After this sequence, `y` should contain the rounded value. Adjust the distance between the two set bits in the constant `9` in order to adjust the number of bits that are rounded off. The value `3` rounds off one bit. The value `5` rounds off two bits. The value `17` rounds off four bits, and so on.

This sequence of instruction is attributed to Veltkamp and is typically used in “Dekker multiplication”. [This page](http://proval.lri.fr/gallery/Dekker.fr.html) has some references.

Comment: That looks clever and gives me what I asked for, so I have no choice but to accept :) Although Simon is right and my intuitive reasoning that for each epsilon of accuracy, there has to be a rounding precision which will yield results correct to that precision was unfortunately flawed. Looks like I have to refactor...

Comment: That **is** clever.

Comment: If I change the question slightly and request a range representing accepted error, rather than its approximation by rounding, does it make numerical sense to define it as `double start = y & CLEAR_LOWER_3_MANTISSA_BITS; double end = start | SET_LOWER_3_MANTISSA_BITS` ? That' assuming 'rounding  3 bits' means 4th bit is the last precision bit. I *think* I should be interested in a range which has approximately the same number of represented values lower and higher than the rounded value `x`.

Comment: @turin The same problem already pointed out by Simon is still present: without additional information, you can not rely on the `x` you would have obtained if you computed using reals not to be on the other side of one of the borders that you thus define than the `x` actually computed with floats, or two very close `float` results to straddle this border.

Comment: @turin if you want a correct error bound that allows to predict that two computations results might have been the same had the computation been done with reals, you can either analyse the algorithm statically (I hate this exercise because errors compound, and you have to take it into account, but it's definitely doable) or…

Comment: @turin … use interval arithmetics **during** the computations (rounding the lower bound downwards and the upper bound upwards at each step), so that you end up with an interval of floats guaranteed to contain the real result. This is becoming a new question, one I might not have chosen to answer (my interest is the low-level, bit-twiddling aspects of floating-point, but I am not competent in numerical analysis).