# Eliminating floating point errors with bit masks in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point

Say I have the problem that I want to calculate a large number of doubles and each time I calculate a new double, I want to check to see if I've seen this double before. What is the best (fastest) way of doing this?

If the doubles were exact I'd create a `set` and check for membership which is O(log n), or a hash set with O(1). But they are not exact, and thus I'd need to loop through all previously seen doubles and check if they are within some tolerance of the newly calculated double, which is slow: O(n). My idea is to keep only the (say) first 30 bits of the double, giving a precision of 2^-30 in the set and check if those are equal. Is this a good idea or is there a better way? And how would one go about keeping only the 30 most significant bits of a double?

Comment: Just right out of a head, why not to keep 2 sets/arrays, first with original calculated values and second with rounded values. So to check number in second array and still have 'full double' when you need it from first array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583249/how-to-round-a-double-float-to-binary-precision

Comment: Re “they are not exact”: This is the wrong model. In the C++ model, as in IEEE-754, each floating-point object represents one number exactly (or is a NaN). The operations on them approximate real-number arithmetic. This difference is essential for analyzing, designing, proving, and debugging floating-point computations.

Comment: Re “Is this a good idea or is there a better way?”: No, this is not a good way. Any attempt to partition the floating-point numbers necessarily either magnifies some errors or breaks transitivity (failing to partition). You should probably back up and explain why you want to check if you have seen a `double` previously. There may be a better approach to solving the problem that led you to that, rather than to solving the problem of trying to find whether a nearby `double` has been seen previously.

Comment: @user3124812 - One "rounded value" may be at the high end of its range; another might be in the next range, but at the low end.  Those would have come from original values that are "close enough" to "match".  When you try to resolve this conundrum, you need up with a non-deterministic problem.

Comment: How many values in your "input"?  How many in the "output"?  Some algorithms work better if there are only a few "duplicate" values; others shine when there are many.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the rounding mode, you'll always draw a line, and numbers falling one side of the line, or to the other could be arbitrarily close (1 ulp in case of Float).

So you need to use at least two sets with different rounding, and check if the float with one rounding mode or the other is in the set or the other.

For example, for a tolerance `t`, that would be something like:

```
is_close = ( round(x,t) is in set1) or ( round(x+t/2,t) is in set2 )
set1 add round(x,t)
set2 add round(x+t/2,t)
```

I suggest using floor or ceiling as truncation mode for regularity.

Note 1: `n*t+t-eps` and `n*t-t+eps` for integer `n`and small `0 < eps < t/100`, will be considered close, with a distance near `2 t`, so t should be chosen as half tolerance in above formulation.

Note 2: this is an absolute tolerance. If the purpose is a relative tolerance (truncating bits of the significand - that is reducing precision), then formulation might be a bit more involved for handling binade boundary, but same kind of algorithm should apply (it's just that t would be floating...)

Comment: Aha, I hadn't thought of that, of course there will always be a boundry. I think I will try to use an unordered set with a custom predicate though, as that seems to suit my needs (I think).

Comment: Yes, some hash-based container for getting O(1), not something based on b-tree in O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to determine whether you've previously seen a given value within a certain range (`a` to `b`), then you can do that with a `std::set` of all the previously seen values.  We can use `upper_bound()` to find the first element greater than `a`, and then test whether it is less than `b`:

```
// untested
bool have_seen(const std::set<double>& past, double a, double b)
{
    auto it = past.upper_bound(a);
    return it != past.end() && *it < b;
}
```

(Use `lower_bound` and `<=` if you want to test inclusive range.)

Speed scales as O(log *n*), of course.

You might choose several iterations of `std::nextafter` to get the appropriate `a` and `b` for your value.

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to reduce the precision of a double (and it's not clear that this is the solution to your particular problem), then it's not too difficult if your system uses the common standard binary format.

We can take advantage of the fact that the least-significant digits contain the mantissa, and just set the correct number of those to zero:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

double trunc(double d, int precision) noexcept
{
    // This function requires IEEE-754 binary representations
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559);
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::radix == 2);
    using Integer = std::uint_fast32_t;

    static const auto max_precision = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits;
    if (precision < 1) {
        // invalid
        return 0;
    }
    if (precision >= max_precision) {
        // no-op
        return d;
    }

    auto& i = reinterpret_cast<Integer&>(d);
    static_assert(sizeof i >= sizeof d);
    auto mask = ~Integer{} << (max_precision - precision);
    i &= mask;

    return d;
}
```

Demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (double d: {100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106,
                    200, 202, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210}) {
        std::cout << d << " -> " << trunc(d, 5) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
100 -> 100
101 -> 100
102 -> 100
103 -> 100
104 -> 104
105 -> 104
106 -> 104
200 -> 200
202 -> 200
206 -> 200
207 -> 200
208 -> 208
209 -> 208
210 -> 208
```

Whether this is actually what you *need* is hard to tell.  It may be useful if you want to gather results into histogram buckets:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
    std::normal_distribution<double> dist(0.5,0.1);

    std::map<double,std::size_t> histogram;
    for (int i = 0;  i < 10000;  ++i) {
        auto d = trunc(dist(gen), 5);
        ++histogram[d];
    }

    for (auto const& [value, freq]: histogram) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << std::setw(5)
                  << value << ": " << std::string(freq/50, '*') << '\n';
    }
}
```

```
0.203: 
0.211: 
0.219: 
0.227: 
0.234: 
0.242: 
0.250: 
0.266: 
0.281: *
0.297: *
0.312: **
0.328: ***
0.344: ***
0.359: *****
0.375: ******
0.391: *******
0.406: ********
0.422: *********
0.438: **********
0.453: ***********
0.469: ************
0.484: ************
0.500: *************************
0.531: **********************
0.562: ******************
0.594: **************
0.625: *********
0.656: *****
0.688: **
0.719: *
0.750: 
0.781: 
0.812: 
0.844:
```

Although this normal distribution *looks* skewed, that's just because the bucket size changes at 0.5, when the exponent increases.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that will work even if you can't afford to hold all the doubles in RAM.

1. Collect the list of doubles.  O(N)
2. Sort them.  O(N*logN)
3. Scan through the list.  Foreach item, either output it or toss it, depending on how close it is to the last output value.  O(n)

If the "test for 'close'" is costly, note that this algorithm performs the test only N times.  Some proposed algorithms are O(N*M) where N is input count and M is output count.

Further note that the output is non-deterministic.  By this, I mean that rearranging the input list could change *which* doubles are kept and which are tossed.  This caution probably applies to any and all algorithms.